# debugging list in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

All my colegas and I are facing a hangup problem with visual studio 2010 while debugging.

Every time i try to watch in a list, by clicking the '+' symbol into the watch windows, VS2010 hangs up.

Any ideas to solve the problem ?

THx

Answer (score 0):

Is the list of fixed content *and* each element having simple properties?

If not, e.g. items are generated as needed, item properties are calculated dynamically, then you might be hitting problems with needing to run application code while otherwise stopped in the debugger. This is particularly a problem if locks and concurrency are involved (e.g. property is waiting on a lock held by a thread that is blocked by the debugger).